# International Lang content in HTML format is rendered as ?? in screen - from Spring controller

Tags: spring, internationalization

I have a spring controller which will return a HTML content that may be in any language - content will be received from external service, when its displayed in browser it displays ??. I have Chinese lang fonts installed in my machine. When i checked in Charles proxy tool - response coming from application has ??.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/getCustomPage", method="get", produces="text/html")
public String getCustomPage(){

String content = "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'><html><body><table class='specs'> <tbody><tr class='header'> <th colspan='2'> <h2> 11 英寸 MacBook Air </h2> </th> </tr> "
                + "</tbody></table></body></html>";


return content;

}
```

I have configured org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter in my web.xml to UTF-8 and forceEncoding set to true. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: What's the encoding of your (source) class file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `produces="text/html;charset=utf-8"` instead of `"produces=text/html"` in your RequestMapping.